# PHP Number formatter not found

Tags: php, ubuntu

I've tried installing it, enabling it, everything. Nothing is working. INTL does not show up in php -m.

It installs fine with sudo apt install php-intl. but does not show up in the mods-available folder either.

running ubuntu 16.04 with php 7.4, ive even tried php 8.0 but cannot get intl to be installed and enabled.

running out of patience, and i've clicked on every google link i've searched.

Comment: have you tried php7.4-intl?

Comment: I have. I get 'Unable to locate package php7.4-intl' Is there a specific repo I need to add?